# Pass param into function in another file JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

In my `app.js` I have

```
io.sockets.on("connection", connectSocket);
```

and then in a different file I have:

```
const connectSocket = (socket, bitlyAppURL) => {
  socket.once(AUTHENTICATED_CONNECTION_REQUEST, params => {
    connectAuthenticatedSocket(socket, params, bitlyAppURL);
  });

  socket.once("disconnect", disconnectSocket);

  socket.emit(AUTHENTICATE_YOURSELF);
};
```

but I'm not sure how to pass this `bitlyAppURL` into the function in `app.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the callback of `socket.on` :

```
io.sockets.on("connection", socket => connectSocket(socket, bitlyAppURL));
```